# Flagging answers with links to download executables from unverified sources. Yes or no?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I recently reported [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76725422/unity-hub-install-failed-validation-failed-message-whenever-i-try-to-install/77160367#77160367) as the user had posted a [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive) link to an installer executable for [Unity Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)#Unity_(2017%E2%80%93present)). It was declined as it is not content that requires intervention.

I thought this would be a potential issue, since you can't really verify the download and it might contain malware.
This post seems to agree: [Can I post executable binaries to into Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399560/can-i-post-executable-binaries-to-into-stack-overflow/399567#399567).
This post would rather have the users accountable for their actions if they decide to trust the user: [Link only answers recommending to run an executable from unverifiable source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332860/link-only-answers-recommending-to-run-an-executable-from-unverifiable-source/333012#333012)

I could imagine that lots of rookies, who have blind trust in Stack Overflow as a reputable site, might think they are in a safe space and don't see the potential risk.

What do you think?

[image]

Comment: Hum, and one of the other Answers in the same Thread looks also clearly 'ChatGPT' generated to me btw...

Comment: The 'ChatGPT' Answer I was referring to in my previous Comment has now (2d later) been deleted...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You, as a user, can address the problem; edit the post to remove the Google Drive link (and leave a descriptive reason for editing it in the revision notes). *If* you saw a user posting *lots* of links to said downloads in many of their answers (or posts), *then* it would be concern.

Moderator flags, as the response you got states, should be for problems that require the moderators to intervene; users can make edits to posts so for a *single* instance an edit to the post is all that is required. Though you don't have 2k reputation, you can still suggest that edit, and provided you gave a good reason in the verb then it would likely be accepted as a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess I misread the moderator response as "is not in need of any intervention". I haven't even though about suggesting an edit.

Comment: Do we usually do the same thing (removing links via edits) for link-only answers?

Comment: If it's link only then use a "Not an answer" flag, @E_net4 .

Comment: One issue with the suggestion in this answer is that there's no way for a user to tell that there was only a single instance of this occurring. It can be quite difficult to search through a user's answers to see if they've posted similar links before, it's really hard to do if those posts have had the links edited out, and next to impossible to do if previous answers have been deleted. Unless a user can be reasonably confident that there's no pattern, erring on the side of flagging is probably better. A declined flag is better than a potential issue going unaddressed.

Comment: I agree that sometimes it can be hard to find a historical problem, @cigien . At least when I've spotted such users, it's often quite evident that they are being malicious.

Comment: @cigien Then the flag text should be about there being a pattern, or concern by the user that there might be a pattern which they can't see, rather than be about the single instance which they could edit out.

Comment: @Makyen Agreed, the flag text should have been clearer if that was the intent. Of course, that's assuming the OP intended to flag a pattern, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: This opens up a wide gaping hole for "snowshoe spam" where the malware is posted to multiple URLs and perhaps linked to from multiple accounts acting in collusion within a campaign.

Comment: "I guess I misread the moderator response as 'is not in need of any intervention'." This is a reasonable way to read that string IMO. Should something be changed in that (presumably templated) message to disambiguate "is not a problem" and "is a potential problem, but the user can take the recommended action themselves"?

Answer (score 10):

If you raise a moderator flag, you need to make clear what you want them to do. In other words: your flag needs to be actionable by them.

Let's look at your flag:

> Posting a google drive link to a program might be a security issue.

I assume most of us would agree, even the elected janitors on this site. Thanks for making us aware of that fact. Anything else?

Instead you want the moderator to actually do something:

- edit the answer to remove the (malicious) link (because you're below 2K so you can't do that on your own)
- delete the answer
- investigate if this link is used in other posts by the OP or other users that warrant actions against the account(s).

so that should go into your flag text.

It would be nice (but not mandatory) if you can safely check whether the link is indeed malicious as that would give you more reason to expedite things instead of waiting for other curators to pick-up the slack.

Do note that some chat rooms are open for curation / guidance on flagging. If you need another pair of eyes before you raise a flag, don't hesitate to ask there for (strong) opinions.

I won't guarantee that this approach would prevent declined flags ever, but then ones I raised in this style have almost all been marked as helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wasn't 100% confident in my judgment of the post, so I didn't think to suggest any action at all since I'm just a user who has little knowledge of the ruleset of the site, and that the mods will know what to do.  I have raised some flags, also for AI content, but I never suggested any action only ever described the problem and they were all marked as helpful. Just to describe my perspective on this. I will keep your suggestions in mind for the future though!